# Third party JAR containing AspectJ pointcut in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I have an external jar file which inside only one AspectJ class.

```
@Aspect
public class SecurityAspect {

   @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(external.package.Secure)")
 public void doCheck() {}

   @Before("doCheck()")
 public void applyCheck(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
       //sth...
   }

}
```

I want to trigger that Aspect using the `@Secure` annotation in a Spring MVC controller

```
@Secure
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test() {
  System.out.println("test");
}
```

The `aspects-config.xml` has all encessary for considering aspects on my project.

```
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
     <aop:include name="log" /> (non external)
     <aop:include name="sec" />
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <bean id="log"
    class="internal.package.LogAspect"
    factory-method="aspectOf" />

    <bean id="sec"
    class="external.package.SecurityAspect"
    factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

Eclipse do recognize that something is binded to `test()` but when I startup the server, Spring cannot find class `external.package.SecurityAspect`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: external.package.SecurityAspect
```

In my application I already have a non external Aspect that makes log for utility and moving the Security Aspect into the Project's package is working fine.

The most comprehensive (for me) questions I came across:

[this(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093637/cant-add-execution-pointcuts-to-external-jar-classes-with-aspectj-why) but I'm not sure that's totally correct since Eclipse do recognize that also in external Jar... but maybe is my misunderstanding;

[this(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292385/aspectj-in-weaving-external-jar) It makes sense! I removed my external library from maven, removed any pointers on `application-context.xml` (right?) imported by that interface, startup and... `Error creating bean with name 'log' defined in file [path/to/aspects-config.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory method 'aspectOf()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is static.` (why do complains about `log` aspect?)

[this(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268613/aspectj-functions-through-external-library) talking about `<context:load-time-weaver />` but it seems not working once added on my application context xml.

THis issue is only if I use EXTERNAL JAR not in the same package.

Can someone better clarify if it is actually not possible (this(3)) or possible make external Aspect to import in projects as a third party library?

Comment: The `aspectOf` should be used for aspects written in the traditional AspectJ syntax (the `aspect` type). With an `@Aspect` annotated class you should not use the factory method and just create an instance of the bean.

Comment: Did not expected that this particular actually solved my problem (incredible O_O) you're awesome, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M. Deinum in comments below noticed that `factory-method="aspectOf"` usage is not necessary with non `aspect` types (then for all my `@Aspect` it is not).

Removed that, startup, no exceptions and now I have a working aspect.